# Endian independency in C

Tags: c, microcontroller

In a microcontroller project written in C, we defined the following macros to access different bytes of a multi byte variable (4 byte `long`):

```
#define BYTE_0(var)         (*((unsigned char*) &var))
#define BYTE_1(var)         (*(((unsigned char*) &var) + 1))
#define BYTE_2(var)         (*(((unsigned char*) &var) + 2))
```

`BYTE_0()` accesses least significant byte, and so on. This is because we find that in case we need to access different bytes of a multi-byte variable separately (the micro in 8 bit), accessing the bytes using the code above produces fewer number of lines of code in assembly. As the code memory size is only 15K, few bytes are sometimes precious.

The micro we're using is little-endian. I'm wondering if we port the code to another micro which is big-endian architecture, will the code above work? In other words, does C standard guarantee that `(*((unsigned char*) &var))` will give the least significant byte of `var`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what microcontroller is this?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: OKI ML610Q411.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your macro does not work, it assumes little endian architecture. The C standard guarantees nothing in the case of your code. Endian-independent code is typically written with bit-wise operators, because they behave the same way no matter where the ls byte is allocated.

`some_long & 0xFF` is guaranteed by the C standard to give you the ls byte no matter endianess, while `(uint8_t*)&some_long` is endian-dependent.

This link answers your question in detail: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/
Do a macro similar to the one in listing 12 with bitwise shift and bitwise AND, and it will be portable.

Comment: "Your macro does not work" - I was thinking the same. Just needed some clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is what [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) means. Your code won't work on machines with opposite endianness.

And I am not even entirely sure that doing such manual optimization matters. Perhaps a better compiler would optimize better...

Comment: unfortunately, this kind of optimization mattered in our case. long story short - we filled up ~15K code memory, then we needed to implement a must have new feature our client demanded much later after final release of the product. this was because of a hardware flaw discovered much later. we began code optimization, keeping in mind not to break maintainability. every byte of optimization helped us and we were able to free ~2K memory.

Comment: Did you consider upgrading or changing the compiler?

Comment: there is only one compiler available that we are using.

Answer (score 2):

No

```
#define BYTE_0(var)         (*((unsigned char*) &var))
```

will give you a byte related to the nature of the processor/memory controller not necessarily even a byte from the variable var.  Ideally if var were 0x12345678 you would hope to see 0x12 on some systems and 0x78 on others.

```
#define BYTE_0(var)         (var&0xFF)
```

gives you the least significant byte of var for any system *ASSUMING* var is the same on every system.

to complete the list.

```
#define BYTE_0(var)         ((var>> 0)&0xFF)
#define BYTE_1(var)         ((var>> 8)&0xFF)
#define BYTE_2(var)         ((var>> 16)&0xFF)
#define BYTE_3(var)         ((var>> 24)&0xFF)
```

DO NOT use bitfields instead of shifting and masking, bitfields do not port from compiler to compiler, endians the same or different.  bitfields are "implementation defined" and every possible messed up thing you can think of can be found out there in compilers.

be careful trying to reverse your question and build a variable from bytes:

```
var = (b3<<24)|(b2<<16)|(b1<<8)|(b0<<0);
```

if b3,b2,b1,b0 are defined as 8 bit variables the compiler does not have to promote them to 32 bit before shifting.  On some systems/compilers the above code would produce the desired effect of placing four bytes into a 32 bit variable.  But on other systems var = b0 is what the above code is saying to do because b1 is an 8 bit variable shift it left 8 and you are left with zeros, likewise shift b2 16 and b3 24 and you end up with

```
var = 0 | 0 | 0 | b0;
```

I prefer

```
var = 0;
var <<= 8; var |= b3;
var <<= 8; var |= b2;
var <<= 8; var |= b1;
var <<= 8; var |= b0;
```

or

```
var = b3;
var <<= 8; var |= b2;
var <<= 8; var |= b1;
var <<= 8; var |= b0;
```

which port quite nicely.  And the optimizer should give you similar/same code as a single line of C with typedefs or a bitfield solution.

Comment: check: "... will give you the least significant byte address of var not the ...".

Comment: same answer as Lundin, the checked answer, just written another way, not well written I understand that.  Your byte_0 It will give you a byte somewhere in the vicinity of the var variable perhaps one of the bytes in var, but not the lsbyte of var every time.  a shift and mask will (assuming var is the same across platforms)

Comment: well i understand your point. i was talking about that you mentioned "will give you the least significant byte **address** of var", but it should be "will give you the least significant byte". I mean it will be the content, not the address.

Comment: I meant it will not be the byte because it is not, it will use the address to determine what byte to take, not necessarily the least significant of the variable.  You have to know the nuances of the specific memory controller for the specific processor/platform to know what byte you will get based on a particular address.  Definitely not a portable/universal definition.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. You've struck on the reason why little endian is better to work with than big endian.

Also consider that casting to different integer sizes does not require any pointer arithmetic.

It's also wrong to assume that `long` will always be 4 bytes. Unfortunately the going standard for x64 for example is LP64, that is `int` was left behind as the 4 byte integer.

Comment: -1 for subjective answer. The conclusion pretty much every little vs big endian research comes up with, is that neither form is better or worse. In this case, big endian is only worse because the OP is apparently used to little endian, and therefore expects big endian to behave just as little endian does...

Comment: @MattJoiner: the micro i am working with has 4 byte long. that's what i've included in the question. anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think the down vote is a bit harsh because Matt has got a (marginal) point.  With little endian, casting a pointer to a smaller sized type preserves the dereferenced value (as long as it fits into the smaller type).

Comment: Downvote only because I don't think eternal, subjetive (pointless) discussions such as big vs little endian, coding style, preferred programming language etc etc belong on this site. There's programmers.stackexchange.com for such. The answer is good, apart from the subjective comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a portable way of accessing the bytes of a 4 byte integer, you either use a #define to change the macros depending on architecture,

```
#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define OFFSET_0 0
#define OFFSET_1 1
#define OFFSET_2 2
#else
#define OFFSET_0 3
#define OFFSET_1 2
#define OFFSET_2 1
#endif



#define BYTE_0(var)         (*(((unsigned char*) &var) + OFFSET_0))
#define BYTE_1(var)         (*(((unsigned char*) &var) + OFFSET_1))
#define BYTE_2(var)         (*(((unsigned char*) &var) + OFFSET_2))
```

or, and this is preferable IMO, if your architecture supports shifts of more than 1 bit.

```
#define BYTE_0(var)         ((var) & 0xFF)
#define BYTE_1(var)         (((var) >> 1 * CHAR_BIT) & 0xFF)
#define BYTE_2(var)         (((var) >> 2 * CHAR_BIT) & 0xFF)
```

which works even for non lvars (e.g. the results of expressions, literals) and is portable.

Comment: yes, the platform supports shifting more than one bit. but `(((var) >> 1 * CHAR_BIT) & 0xFF)` will generate few lines of extra code than `(*(((unsigned char*) &var) + OFFSET_1))`.

Comment: @Donotalo:  well in that case use the first example.